# What can I turn off on windows XP to free up memory without breaking everything

Tags: windows-xp, performance, services

I seem to have a lot of services that start up on windows, many of which I have no use of (to my knowledge). are there any services which are on by default which I won't really miss and which will free up my system so it works a bit better.

This question is specific to XP, I have a vista laptop which I will ask the same question for.

Answer (score 4):

Try [BlackViper](http://www.blackviper.com/) for some good configurations of varying levels for most Windows OSs. For example, XP SP3 is [here](http://www.blackviper.com/WinXP/servicecfg.htm).

Also, try using the [Autoruns tool from Sysinternals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to get rid of Adobe and QuickTime startup apps.

Then, uninstall all apps you don't use. Really - do you use that Noughts-and-crosses game all that often?

Finally, use lightweight equivalents of big apps - [Foxit Reader](http://foxitsoftware.com) instead of Adobe Reader.