# Which windows XP services can I disable without major consequence?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, services

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Windows services can I safely disable?](https://superuser.com/questions/94/what-windows-services-can-i-safely-disable)

I want to disable some Windows XP services to make PC run faster.

I am not going to be using the PC for anything complex, but will need to leave networking enabled.

Which ones can I get rid of without fear of breaking something.

On a side note, which removed services will give me the biggest performance hike?

Thanks!