# What Windows 7 services can safely be stopped without degrading experience?

Tags: windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Windows services can I safely disable?](https://superuser.com/questions/94/what-windows-services-can-i-safely-disable)

Windows 7 is a great OS, no doubt about that.

However, there might be some things one can do to improve speed and performance and the thing that comes to mind is this one regarding Windows 7 services:

**What Windows 7 services can be stopped without degrading the experience?**

Meaning, these services are still stopped after a reboot and Windows 7 still works very fine.

Why asking this? Because it looks like one simply can do without some of the 120+ started services. :)

(Couldn't find any on this on [www.blackviper.com](http://www.blackviper.com))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled these, and things are working flawlessly and all nice effects (taskbar preview, winkey-tab, ...) are still here:

[image]

edit: apart from those there's a whole lot more set to manual and not started, so maybe it's a better reference to show what is started:

[image]

Comment: That's some compilation of services, cool! I'll try this out and get back!