# What services can I stop to keep system minimally running?

Tags: windows-7, windows, services, kiosk

I've narrowed down Windows services to the following required:

[image: Minimal Services]

Which of these services can I safely stop/disable to "dummify" Windows 7 where basic network connectivity and remote desktop still work?

NOTE: This is not like [other questions](https://superuser.com/questions/94/what-windows-services-can-i-safely-disable) related to boot time or performance. This is related to a Kiosk PC.

Comment: I would vote my own question to close as duplicate, but I don't have that rep yet: http://superuser.com/questions/94/what-windows-services-can-i-safely-disable

Comment: Wait, I just read your comment and voted to close as a dupe since that's what you wanted, but your edit above seems to suggest otherwise? Which is it? If your comment is no longer relevant delete it to prevent further confusion.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is from 2009 and the answers deal with Win XP.  I'm not sure how much use the information will be for Win 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of listing the slew of services to be kneecapped, I'll share the shorter list of just what to execute:

In the NIC's properties, uncheck, or even uninstall all things except TCP/IP4 including and especially Server, Workstation and all of the Link Discovery junk that only seems to work at Bill Gates mansion.

In Services like the menu you attached, run only the DNS client and disable DHCP client in lieu of entering your own legal address and Google's 8.8.8.8 / 8.8.4.4 servers.

Unset the Default Use NetBios over TCP/IP in your NIC's properties.

sc config tcpip6 start= disabled

Since only Google uses TCP/IPv6 on their WANs.

Windows Update and the endless patches, patches for the patches and horizon full of .NetService Pack Critical Sec Updates are successfully avoided in my network by defining a FW outbound policy too lengthy to describe generically.